# What is the fastest way to retrieve at runtime big powers of two in decimal string format?

Tags: vb.net

In order to display big numbers I need to be able to retrieve the powers of two in decimal string format. The following code is the best I could do, is there a faster way?

```
Public NotInheritable Class TwoPowerOf

    Private DecimalString As String = ""

    Public Sub New(ByVal MyInteger As Integer)
        If MyInteger > -256 And MyInteger < 1024 Then
            Me.DecimalString = GetTwoPowerOf(MyInteger)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Me.DecimalString
    End Function

    Protected Function GetTwoPowerOf(ByVal MyInteger As Integer) As String
        Dim result As String = ""
        Dim d As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
        '...
        d.Add(2, "4")
        d.Add(1, "2")
        d.Add(0, "1")
        d.Add(-1, "0.5")
        d.Add(-2, "0.25")
        d.Add(-3, "0.125")
        d.Add(-4, "0.0625")
        d.Add(-5, "0.03125")
        d.Add(-6, "0.015625")
        d.Add(-7, "0.0078125")
        d.Add(-8, "0.00390625")
        ' ...
        result = d.Item(MyInteger)
        Return result
    End Function
End Class
```

And retreiving is something like this:

```
Sub whatever()
    Dim MyInteger as Integer
    Dim MyDecimalString as String = New TwoPowerOf(MyInteger).ToString
    Console.WriteLine(MyDecimalString)
End Sub
```

Or, is there a way to convert big binary numbers into decimals without using the powers of two?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/exponentiation-operator

Comment: @Dave B - Nope, it's not. Calculating the big powers of two at runtime is a very expensive operation, e.g.'2 ^ (-256) ' could take minutes. I'm looking to improve the speed and provide the calculated values at runtime. (It's easy to sum few decimal strings)

Comment: Have a look at Microsofts BitConverter class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @StormCloud - is not my case, I already have the values converted in bits, and .net numeric types can't store more than 64 bits anyway. But thanks for replay.

Comment: The [**`Decimal`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(v=vs.110).aspx) can hold 128 bits. There's also [**`BigInteger`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) which can hold as big number as your system memory (RAM) allows, though it doesn't support decimals.

Comment: @Visual Vincent - The decimal holds only 96 bits, and from the rest of 32 bits only 6 are used: 1 bit for sign, and 5 bits for the number of decimal digits (can mark 0 to 28 digits). And, as I already said, I dont need a bit holding class like BigInteger, because I have my own class for holding the bits. The matter is converting those bits into decimal values to be displayed on the screen. Actually, using the above method it takes about 4 seconds to display a number having 512 decimal digits, from which only the first ~160 decimal digits are precise.

Comment: `as I already said, I dont need a bit holding class like BigInteger` - You never said that. You only said that you have it stored in bits (not how nor where), and since you want to return a base 10 result `BigInteger` would be great at least for the integral numbers. - `The matter is converting those bits into decimal values to be displayed on the screen.` - Again, `BigInteger` for the integral powers of two.

Comment: @Visual Vincent - Well, my bad, sorry, I didn't explicitly explained that but I thought is obvious that I need a solution to cover both parts of the problem: integer part and decimals part, not just only the half of it. In fact, with my current "solution" the integer part are displayed much more faster than decimals part.

Comment: That you needed both solutions there was no doubt about, but no built-in solution exists for such large decimal numbers so I suggested the closest possible: a built-in solution for the integral numbers. Though I just found a separate library that Microsoft created called [**BigRational**](http://bcl.codeplex.com/releases/view/42782). I've never used it but you should give it a try, it seems to be what you need.

Comment: @Visual Vincent - Thank you for the BigRational, I will study it.